# How do I plot different variables from the same column while leaving out the NAs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, group-by

How do I plot different variables from the same column while leaving out the NAs?

I am working on a EA Sports Fifa players statistics dataset

The code I wrote is:

```
plotageleague <- df %>% 
  group_by(League) %>% 
  summarise(age = mean(Age))

options(repr.plot.width = 12, repr.plot.height = 8)

ggplot()+
  geom_histogram(df, mapping = aes(Age, fill = League))+
  geom_vline(plotageleague, mapping = aes(xintercept = age), color = "red", size = 1.5)+
  geom_text(plotageleague, mapping = aes(x = age+3, y = 65, label = round(age,digits = 2)))+
  facet_wrap(League~.)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  labs(y = "Frequency", title = "", caption = "")
```

The League column contains 12 different football leagues, each as a different variable and NAs, which becomes the 13th plot. I don't want that. I only want the statistics of the leagues that have players assigned to them (I only assigned players to 12 leagues of the actually existing 30+ leagues so the rest of the players have NA in the Column "league")

Comment: `filter(!is.na(League))` will help.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses tidy to drop na's from League column from df. You also seem to be creating another dataframe plotageleague. I'm not sure if you want na's included there. The way you have it set up, they are.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   drop_na(League) %>% 
   ggplot(.)+
   geom_histogram(mapping = aes(Age, fill = League))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.